# Dynamically change style of div if number is greater than 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have a child div that has a numerical value in it (0 by default) - what I want to do is change the styling of the parent div when the value inside the child div is > 0.

Issue is this is a basket counter, so when the user adds to basket this number (child div) changes automatically - which is the issue I'm facing. I can get the styling of the child div to change if > 0 but can't get the parent div styling to change AND I can't get it to work in a dynamic way i.e. it only works for me on page reload/refresh.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you at least show us what you have done/tried so far?

Comment: Please post the code HTML and JavaScript you have written so far, a working JSFiddle.net / JSBin.com would be great

Comment: This is what I've been toying with:

$('#1').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(string, this.innerHTML) > 0;
}).css({'background-color':'red'});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v9pk6ec4/ is the jsfiddle - background gets applied on local but not here for some reason